# Searching through an ID children/children Node for specific values

Tags: html, vba

I have a list on a web page (a very repetitive task at work) from which I need to select a few elements, then press a button to select them (the part with pressing the button is not an issue because I know how to do that).
I found that the options from which I can choose are Children/CHildren nodes of the ID that contains/ represents the table. This seems rather complicated to do with a MACRO.
**Is there a way to do something like getElementbyID and call/search for the "Title"? Since it seems to be the unique value for each option?**

The parent html code is shown below:

```
class="mstrListBlockItem" title="2018 KW 05" style="margin-top: 0px;"
class="mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">2018&nbsp;KW&nbsp;05</div><div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="2018 KW 04"><div class="mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">2018&nbsp;KW&nbsp;04</div></div><div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="2018 KW 03"><div class="mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">2018&nbsp;KW&nbsp;03</div></div><div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="2018 KW 02"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general solution, you could use the different "properties" of the elements to find the ones you need to click. Properties like ".innertext", ".Children", a more complete documentation is listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_properties(v=vs.110).aspx).

The following code loops through the items in a class named: "substitutethis with the classnames untill you loop through the one you need". (I think items are the children you mean, but I am not sure about the terminology and cannot verify at this point in time.)

First initializing the objects and variables:

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim objelement As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://the.websitethatcontainsyour.list"

        'wait until first page loads
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

'Start looping through the elements:
Set elements0d = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("substitutethis with the classnames untill you loop through the one you need")
For Each item In elements0d
    MsgBox (elements0d.item.className & elements0d.item.innerText)                
    If elements0d.item.innerText = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("somesheet which value your entry in the list needs to equal").Range("B2").Value & " (FR)" Then
        MsgBox ("already logged in")
        logged_in = True                    
    End If
Next
```

Another way to loop through the elements in the list would be:

```
Set elements0d = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("substitutethis with the classnames untill you loop through the one you need")
For Each item In elements0d
    MsgBox (elements0d.item.className & elements0d.item.innerText)                
    If elements0d.item.innerText = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("somesheet which value your entry in the list needs to equal").Range("B2").Value & " (FR)" Then
        MsgBox ("already logged in")
        logged_in = True                    
    End If
Next
```

Or:

```
Set elements0d = ie.document.getElementsByName("substitutethis with the element names untill you loop through the one you need")

Set elements0d = ie.document.getElementsById("substitutethis with the element Id's untill you loop through the one you need")
```

Applied to your data the above solution could look like:

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim objelement As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://the.websitethatcontainsyour.list"

        'wait until first page loads
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

dim seaching_through_classes(0 to 10) as string
seaching_through_classes(0) = "mstrListBlockItem"
seaching_through_classes(1) = "mstrBGIcon_ae mstrListBlockItemName"

dim searchterm as string
searchterm = "2018 KW 05"

for loop_through_classes = 0 to 1
    'Start looping through the elements:
    Set elements0d = ie.document.getElementsByClassName(search_through_classes(loop_through_classes))
    For Each item In elements0d
        MsgBox (elements0d.item.className & elements0d.item.title)                
        If elements0d.item.innerText = "2018 KW 05" Then
            MsgBox ("Found title: " + "2018 KW 05")
        End If
    Next
Next loop_through_classes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Both of them were very useful !!

Answer (score 1):

You could choose all DIV tags in your site and then check their inner HTML if they contain text: title=".
 Something like that:

```
Dim oDivs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim dv As IHTMLElement

Set oDivs = iBody.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each dv In oDivs
    If InStr(dv.innerHTML, "title=""") Then
        'some code here
    End If
Next dv
```

where iBody is the body the piece of the HTML where your buttons are expected to be.